# Ionic 4, Angular: problems showing OK and Cancel buttons with <ion-datetime>, <ion-select>

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

I'm working on a project on ionic 4, but by putting the **ion-datetime** tag in my HTML code, the OK and Cancel buttons are displayed incorrectly. The same thing happens to me when I put the ion-alert and the **ion-select** tag. I show the images **[link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/763yV.jpg)** and **[link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn1s3.jpg)** that detail my problem:

I show HTML fragment below:

HTML fragment for the **ion-datetime** tag:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked" color="primary">
     <ion-text color="light">Fecha de Nacimiento</ion-text>
    </ion-label>
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY" monthShortNames="ene, feb, mar, abr, may, jun, jul, ago, sep, oct, nov, dic" color="light" placeholder="Seleccione fecha" required></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

HTML fragment for the **ion-select** tag:

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="educa.Nivel_Academico" name="Nivel_Academico" placeholder="Nivel de Educación">
     <ion-select-option value="1">Técnico</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="2">Profesional</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="3">Empírico</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
```

I also show the preferences in my config.xml file:

```xml
... 
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#6600cc" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
...
</platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="2.0.0-beta.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="0.9.0-beta.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="3.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-native-keyboard" spec="2.0.2">
        <variable name="LICENSE" value="TRIAL" />
        <variable name="LIC_ANDROID" value="TRIAL" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.7.1" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in this case, or what solution I could take about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added *okayText* and *cancelText* attribute on **ion-select**

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="educa.Nivel_Academico" name="Nivel_Academico" placeholder="Nivel de Educación" okText="OK" cancelText="cancel">
    ...
<ion-select>
```

and for datetime I think you haven't used attribute correctly. The code should looks like this:

```
<ion-datetime display-format="DD MMM YYYY" month-short-names="ene, feb, mar, abr, may, jun, jul, ago, sep, oct, nov, dic" color="light" placeholder="Seleccione fecha" required></ion-datetime>
```

You can find more details on [Ionic Official Docs.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components) check [ion-select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select) and [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) component for more details on it.